# Django test fails to run migrations

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm trying to run a test script, following [this django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) (which is the version being used here). It quickly fails with a long stack. I've selected what's the possible culprit.

```
  File "/home/user11/app-master/en/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/home/user11/app-master/app/colegiados/migrations/0002_auto_20200128_1646.py", line 185, in migrate
    add_sistema_entidade_e_orgao_composicao(apps, sistema)
  File "/home/user11/app-master/app/colegiados/migrations/0002_auto_20200128_1646.py", line 16, in add_sistema_entidade_e_orgao_composicao
    user = get_user(apps)
  File "/home/user11/app-master/app/colegiados/migrations/0002_auto_20200128_1646.py", line 7, in get_user
    return User.objects.filter(
  File "/home/user11/app-master/en/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 318, in __getitem__
    return qs._result_cache[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As a workaround, I modified django's query.py

```
if qs._result_cache:
  return qs._result_cache[0]
else: 
  return ""
```

Which worked, until the next error:

```
  File "/home/user11/app-master/en/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/home/user11/app-master/app/core/migrations/0016_auto_20201120_0934.py", line 106, in migrate
    sistema = Sistema.objects.get(nom_alias=sistema)
  File "/home/user11/app-master/en/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user11/app-master/en/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 439, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
__fake__.DoesNotExist: Sistema matching query does not exist.
```

Now I'm stuck. The test_database gets created with all the tables up to these migrations' errors, with the vast majority lacking any data. Among those that are empty is the table that this last error seems to refer to.

Note that I'm not the developer, I had no hand in creating the DB being used nor any of the migrations. I strongly suspect the database (Postgres12) has to be created/restored from a "minimal" backup before migrations can work properly. Could that be the reason for these failures? If so, what are my options for running a django test that doesn't alter the deployed database? Any options for running the test as a query block and then doing a rollback, as it's using Postgres?

Comment: Your migration is looking for a User. Data migrations should work fine on empty databases so you need to fix your migration to skip doing the work if there isn't any data to migrate.

Comment: Like I said, most of the tables are being created empty, the data isn't on the migration scripts. It looks for a user in that first one but cannot find any because the table is empty. How would I make it skip insertions/specific migrations while running the test?

Comment: If you can post the code from the file `/app/colegiados/migrations/0002_auto_20200128_1646.py` we can probably help you out. Most likely that will not be the only file with bad error handling

Comment: I've checked the get_user from that migration file. The function is these 2 lines: `User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User'`, then `return User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).order_by('pk')[0]`. Since the auth_user table is empty, this will always fail, filter or no. Putting the return inside a `if User.objects.order_by('pk')` solves the problem the same way as that query.py fix.

Comment: Do something like 
```
user = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).order_by('pk')
if user:
```

This is only one query versus the other that is 2, and fetches all the data for the if

Comment: A decent bit of optimization, but that still doesn't solve the real issue of tables being empty and thus causing failures when some data is expected.

Comment: As far as I know, all tests run on a clean database (unless you load some fixtures or reuse db between tests that don't cleanup). 
Normal `TestCase` wraps each test in a transaction that is rollback so the tables outside the test are always empty.
`LiveServerTestCase` doesn't use transactions but the tables should be truncated at the end of the tests.
In both cases you start with a fresh database and set it up as you need for the test.

The LiveServerTestCase allows you to use tools like Selenium as it runs the actual server for the test.

Comment: I'm using LiveServerTestCase because the test uses Selenium, Django is only the backend, the site/system proper is Ant/Rest, so it tests whether the site, the user experience, is working as intended. The Selenium test runs successfully by itself, run from a python3 call, but within the django test, i'm having this trouble with the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some talk to the rest of the team, it was decided to reset all migrations to ensure this type of problem no longer happens. Maybe not the "expected" solution, but a decent solution.